# Что это за язык?

Tags: php, webasyst

```
{foreach $frontend_category as $_}{$_}{/foreach}

{if !empty($filters)}
```

Код очень похож на PHP, но я уверен, что это не он, т.к код PHP выглядит след. образом

```
<?php
foreach ($frontend_category as $_){
  $_  
}
?>
```

Этот код я получил из Webasyst

Comment: Похоже на какой-то шаблонизатор

Comment: Ну так сходили бы на сайт вебасиста и полистали документацию https://developers.webasyst.ru/docs/templates/

Answer (score 0):

Это шаблонизатор Smarty, всем спасибо ♥
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smarty